# Visual Studio Intellisense - treat .C files as C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Visual Studio Professional 2019 Intellisense treats files with the .C extension as being C code, rather than C++. For example, simple namespace using statements are underlined as errors.

The .C (uppercase) extension is common when working on Linux, so I'm losing the benefit of Intellisense when working on cross-platform code.

Is it possible to convince Intellisense that .C extensions denotes C++ code? I'm not using any C code, so don't need to worry about the .c/.C distinction.

Tried adding a file extension mapping for .C (Tools->Options->Text Editor->File Extension) but all I code map to was 'Microsoft Visual C/C++'. This did not resolve the problem.

Comment: *The .C (uppercase) extension is common when working on Linux* - this is not true. This is true, if you replace "Linux" with "gcc" and "common" with "a few times in 90s". [.C as a file extension for C++ is not portable](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27140404)

Comment: The simple solution would be to use Linux tools to change all the extensions if you can.